# Expo camera reference not being recognized

Tags: reactjs, native, expo

I haven’t included any code because it’s basic...I hooked up the camera and camera ref.it seems to record and stop but I cannot access the promise and when I hover over the method it just says any so basically it’s not recognizing the cam ref object?...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It definitely helps if you include your code. How else do you think anyone can help you? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn’t include code because it’s standard... I made a camera reference per Expo Camera but I can’t access the promise even though both functions seem to work

Comment: Well that's your choice, but the etiquette on SO is to share code and people will help. Maybe it's standard/basic code, but I don't know that, and I can't offer advice on something I can't see.

Comment: True... I thought maybe it was a known issue... when  I get home I will post code...